# A differential equation $e^{-2 x} y+y''+y'=e^{-3 x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$e^{-2x}y+y''+y'=e^{-3x}$

I have encounter some difficulty while solving this equation.
What I can do is only to find that $e^{-x}$ is a solution.

Comment: There's a standard method, called reduction of order, for finding the second solution, having already found the first. See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order

Answer (score 1):

Solve the following DEQ:

$$\tag 1 y'' + y' + e^{-2x}y = e^{-3x}$$

That exponential term is nasty, so lets see if we can get rid of it somehow.

Guiding hints:

- Let $t = -e^{-x}$
- This substitution gives us $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dt}{dx}\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -t \dfrac{dy}{dt}$
- Write a similar expression for $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$
- Using these three substitutions, re-write $(1)$

You will now have the DEQ:

$$\tag 2 y(t)'' + y(t) = -t$$

After solving $(2)$, substitute back for $t$.

**Spoiler**

> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~y(x) = c_1 \cos(e^{-x}) + c2 \sin(e^{-x}) + e^{-x}$

Comment: @amWhy: thanks, thought it was you as I get no other support! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If $y=e^{-x}$, then $y'=-e^{-x}$ and $y''=e^{-x}$. Replace in your equation, which is verified.

By the way, the general solution of your equation is
$$y = e^{-x} + C_1 \cos (e^{-x}) + C_2 \sin(e^{-x})$$

Comment: As I understand that the question is how to find $e^{-x}$ as a solution not to verify that it is a solution.

Comment: You proved that it is a solution. Did they ask you more than that ?